# Insert img src into input onClick

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick

I'm trying to expand on the javascript the you guys helped me with.

The Snippet:

```
<script>
 function changeValue(o){
   document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o.innerHTML;
 }
</script>

<span onclick="changeValue(this)" style="cursor: pointer;">One</span>
<span onclick="changeValue(this)" style="cursor: pointer;">Two</span>
<img src='image.gif' onclick="changeValue(this.src)" />

<input type="text" name="NAME" value="SOMETHING">
```

The spans are working correctly, although I don't actually need them.  I will have all images once I figure this out.

I have tried a few ways, but what I can find is not directly related to my use.

The end goal is to get the img src into the text input with js, preferably somewhat how it already exists.  I feel it's really close.

Comment: Check the console for errors..Try `document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o;`

Comment: want to post that in an answer =) that did the trick, now the spans return object blah blah, but i only needed the img working anyway =)

Comment: The cause of getting `[object]` is passing `this` instead of `this.textContent` or `this.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this.src` will be `src` property of the image object. `o.innerHTML` will try to read `innerHTML` property of the `this.src` which does not exist.

Just use passed argument as value of the input element.

```
document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o;
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/bvdvvosp/2/)

**Edit:** To get the value of the `src` attribute instead of `src` property, use `this.getAttribute('src')`. `this.src` will return the URL of the element.

Comment: using this method is there a way so it only grabs whats in the src? and not the actual src? like if i have src="../images/pic.png" thats what it puts in the box.  right now it puts the url to the src src="http:/site.me/images/pic.png

Answer (score 0):

When you did `this.src` it returns a string rather than a DOM element.

Just simply pass the value that you want to show

```
<script>
 function changeValue(o){
   document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o;
 }
</script>

<span onclick="changeValue(this.innerHTML)" style="cursor: pointer;">One</span>
<span onclick="changeValue(this.innerHTML)" style="cursor: pointer;">Two</span>
<img src='image.gif' onclick="changeValue(this.src)" />

<input type="text" name="NAME" value="SOMETHING">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried run your code, see below.

Also I used **document.querySelector('#testinput')** instead of **document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0]**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function changeValue(val) {
        document.querySelector('#testinput').value = val;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span onclick="changeValue(this.innerHTML)" style="cursor: pointer;">One</span>
    <span onclick="changeValue(this.innerHTML)" style="cursor: pointer;">Two</span>
    <img src='image.gif' onclick="changeValue(this.src)" />
    <input type="text" id="testinput" name="NAME" value="SOMETHING">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this cant work for my current project due to the product not having access to the input fields code to add an ID so I have to go by name.  but this will come in handy for future projects